# How to enable keep alive on CSS,JS and images>

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, css, keep-alive

I have enabled Keepalive on my servlet and JSP pages by adding keepalive header.But [GTMETRIX](http://www.gtmetrix.com) still shows that I should enable keepalive on CSS,JS and images.I am making myproject in java.Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Please, add some code. E.g. add your servlet

Comment: @Ilya Ihave just added `response.addHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
  response.addHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=60000");` im my servlet and JSP page and